# Missing configuration Google Chrome for Multi-Device Hybrid App

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

When I start my MDHA application I get this error message saying that Chrome is missing, but I do have the latest version of Chrome, everything seems to be working ok, but Im wondering why I get this message

[image: Google Chrome Missing]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This warning may appear if you have installed Google Chrome installed for your local user instead of globally for the machine.